# Can’t place button at the same height as my input fields

Tags: html, css

I’d like to have my two inputs at the same height as my button but the button is getting put under.

```css
#startButton {
  height: 90%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 79%;
  position: absolute;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu'>
  Number of colums:
  <br>
  <input id='colsInput' type='number' maxlength='2'>
  <br>
  <br> Number of rows:
  <br>
  <input id='rowsInput' type='number' maxlength='2'>
  <button id='startButton'>Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Because button is position absolutely but inputs aren't?

Comment: No, giving an absolute positioning to the inputs doesnt fix it

Comment: I didn't say that you should add `position: absolute` to inputs.

Comment: So what should I do ? I don't know anything about CSS

Comment: ideal time to begin with CSS basics :-) No advices with no attempts and own research.

Comment: I usually never use it and I'm not intersted in it. Could you just give me a solution please :'( ?

Comment: Don't really know why don't you just break after the second input and put it there, without any styles on it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to add a position to your container `#menu`, like `position: relative;`, then, add a top value to your button `top: 0`;
It should do the trick

```css
#startButton {
  height: 90%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 79%;
  position: absolute;
  outline: 0;
 top: 0;
}
#menu {
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu'>
  Number of colums:
  <br>
  <input id='colsInput' type='number' maxlength='2'>
  <br>
  <br> Number of rows:
  <br>
  <input id='rowsInput' type='number' maxlength='2'>
  <button id='startButton'>Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Victofu i am simply curious why this solution is getting accepted. It does fix you issue ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Do you care to explain how it doesn't fix it ? The button is displayed on the same line... isn't it ?

Comment: that's why am asking :) i didn't say it doesn't fix ... but i don't understand what OP wants and why this is suitable

Comment: `I’d like to have my two inputs at the same height as my button` i don't see them at the same height

Comment: @TemaniAfif I do understand the question as: `at the same top value`, you're right that if the requirement is having the button's height the same as the two input's height, this answer is wrong.

Comment: yes, it's simply confusing ... the question is unclear, and by accepting this anwser it make it even more unclear ... nothing against you of course ! i simply want to understand ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I understand your concern. As a non native english speaker, I might find a signification to the sentence that is not the real one in a proper english. In my language, `height` can be understand as `altitude` as well.

Comment: yes maybe ... i also speak French by the way (c'est ma 2ème langue) but i never thought about this :) maybe too long using CSS :p

Answer (score 0):

Just set a top value.

```css
#startButton {
  height: 90%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 79%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu'>
  Number of colums:
  <br>
  <input id='colsInput' type='number' maxlength='2'>
  <br>
  <br> Number of rows:
  <br>
  <input id='rowsInput' type='number' maxlength='2'>
  <button id='startButton'>Start</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [float property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) :

```css
#startButton {
  height: 90%;
  width: 20%;
  float:right;
  outline: 0;
}
.form {
width:50%;
display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id='menu'>
  <div class="form">
  Number of colums:
  <br>
  <input id='colsInput' type='number' maxlength='2'>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
   Number of rows:
  <br>
  <input id='rowsInput' type='number' maxlength='2'>
  </div>
  <button id='startButton'>Start</button>
</div>
```